# índice não definido (undefined index) PHP $_POST

Tags: php

Bom galera sou Dev Android, mas não manjo muito de WEB, dai então peguei um exemplo de um outro Dev Android no qual ele utiliza um "sistema" online que exibe um mapa e faz alguns cadastros mas sempre que eu abro o página principal aparece notice no php.

[image: Erro no servidor]

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
} 
@include_once('conf/config.php');
@include_once(__PATH__.'/conf/config.php');
require_once(__PATH__.'/package/apl/AplMap.php');


if( preg_match('/^(get-map-content|get-form-create-place|get-form-update-place){1}$/', $_POST['method']) ){ 

    if(preg_match('/^(get-form-update-place){1}$/', $_POST['method'])){
        $apl = new AplMap();
        $arrayPlaces = $apl->getPlacesLightWeight();
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
    require_once(__PATH__.'view/content-location-api-app.php');
}


else if(preg_match('/^(send-map-coords){1}$/', $_POST['method'])
    || preg_match('/^(send-map-coords){1}$/', $_GET['method'])){

    $apl = new AplMap();
    $map = new Map();
    $map->post( $_POST );
    $return = $apl->saveMapCoord( $map );

    echo json_encode(array( 'feedback'=>$return ));
}


else if(preg_match('/^(get-last-map-coords){1}$/', $_POST['method'])
    || preg_match('/^(get-last-map-coords){1}$/', $_GET['method'])){
    $apl = new AplMap();
    $user = new User(1);
    $map = $apl->getLastMapCoord( $user );

    echo json_encode(array( 'map'=>is_null($map) ? '' : $map->getDataJSON() ));
}


else if(preg_match('/^(create-place){1}$/', $_POST['method'])){
    $apl = new AplMap();

    $place = new Place();
    $place->post( $_POST );
    $return = $apl->savePlace( $place );

    echo json_encode(array( 'feedback'=>$return ));
}


else if(preg_match('/^(update-place){1}$/', $_POST['method'])){
    $apl = new AplMap();

    $place = new Place( $_POST['id-place'] );
    $place->post( $_POST );
    $return = $apl->updatePlace( $place );

    echo json_encode(array( 'feedback'=>$return ));
}


else if(preg_match('/^(get-place-data){1}$/', $_POST['method'])){
    $apl = new AplMap();

    $place = new Place( $_POST['id-place'] );
    $place->post( $_POST );
    $place = $apl->getPlace( $place );

    echo json_encode(array( 'place'=>$place->getDataJSON() ));
}


else if(preg_match('/^(get-places-closest){1}$/', $_POST['method'])){
    $apl = new AplMap();

    $place = new Place();
    $place->setLatitude( $_POST['latitude'] );
    $place->setLongitude( $_POST['longitude'] );
    $place->setDistance( $_POST['distance'] );

    $arrayPlaces = $apl->getPlacesClosest( $place );


    // SEND TO CLIENT
        $tam = count($arrayPlaces);
        $arrayJson = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < $tam; $i++){
            $arrayJson[] = $arrayPlaces[$i]->getDataJSON();
        }

        $arrayJson = array('places'=>$arrayJson);
        echo json_encode($arrayJson);
}
```

?>

Comment: Pelo que parece a variável `$_POST['method']` ou a variável `$_POST['method']` não existe. Você sabe se em algum momento elas tem valor?